# What happens to an active flag on a deleted question?

Tags: support, flags

What happens to a flag when the question in question was deleted by a moderator, and it still says active? Does that mean it was a bad flag or it's just going to sit there?

Comment: What question did you flag? Normally flags are "handled" when the question is deleted.

Comment: @AnnaLear I'm not sure what you're able to see as a moderator (I hope everything lol) but here's a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754145/all-php-solutions-is-here-check-this-site-for-php-problems

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, flags are automatically dismissed as helpful when a moderator deletes the question.

There is one exception: when the question is deleted automatically because it meets the [criteria for automatic deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/155160) or via spam/offensive flags from other users. In that case, your custom flag remains active for a human moderator to review what happened since we don't want to make any assumptions about the content of the flag and its relation to the question.

Comment: Ohhh, that makes sense. Thanks a lot! Sorry for creating more work for y'all lol

Comment: @RUJordan No worries. :)

Answer (score 1):

The question you linked to was not deleted by a moderator, it was deleted due to a sufficient number of spam flags from regular users.

In such cases, any flags other than custom moderator flags will be validated as helpful.  Moderator flags will stick around until a moderator actively acts on them, so you can be sure that if you use a custom moderator flag it will always be shown to an actual human moderator.